# Two objects have equivalent sorting criteria

Tags: java, sorting, groovy

I have a sorted ArrayList of maps that i am sorting based on a map key!
I noticed when two objects have equivalent sorting criteria so the two objects is sorted in random behaviour! 
Does anyone have an explanation of how this situation handled and if there is a way to do it so that if a new element has the same sorting criteria to an existing element so it would come afterwards?

Comment: write your comparator such that if values are equal next criteria is index

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a stable sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 2 objects are supposed to be ordered in a specific manner when they are equal in the sorting criteria then you need to add a secondary sorting criteria to enforce that order within the `Comparator`. Otherwise as far as sorting is concerned their order shouldn't matter.

Comment: you mean otherwise the sorting order of those two elements would be completely random ?

Comment: There may be a specific method, but even if there was you can't rely on it. The only way to guarantee a certain order is to implement within the `Comparator`.